# How to build different versions with environment variables

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

According to [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1966) it is not possible to set flags within an electron app with environment variables. I still need to build different versions of the app for dev, staging, pilot and prod.

Internally I would like to use [`electron-node-config`](https://github.com/dw1284/electron-node-config) because it's just easy. But because I have no access to environment variables it's not possible to use `node-config`.

So I thought of having several entry scripts like

```
// index.dev.js
require('./main')({ APP_URL: 'localhost:8080' });

// index.staging.js
require('./main')({ APP_URL: 'https://staging.foo.com' });

// pilot.staging.js
require('./main')({ APP_URL: 'https://pilot.foo.com' });
```

Where my `main.js` file looks *more or less* like this

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow.loadURL(config.APP_URL);
  });
};
```

However, in the electron builder docs there doesn't seem to be an option for specifying an entry file, it always uses `index.js` to package the app, and there isn't much written in the docs for the js api other than

```
const builder = require('electron-builder');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const entry = `index.${env}.js`;

builder.build({
  entry,
  appId: 'com.electron.foo',
  productName: 'foo',
  mac: {
    target: 'zip'
  },
  win: {
    target: 'portable'
  },
  portable: {
    artifactName: 'foo.exe'
  }
});
```

So I tried setting up my package.json like this

```
"scripts": {
  "build:staging": "NODE_ENV=development node scripts/build",
  "build:pilot": "NODE_ENV=pilot node scripts/build",
  "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production node scripts/build"
}
```

However I'm really not sure how to set the entry file for electron builder config. How do I specify an entry file?

Comment: should be nice for begginers if you make clear on comments that `scripts/build` is acctually a your `build.js`. Thanks a lot for this solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this with a hacky bash script

```
#!bin/bash

# make tmp package.json
cp package.json _package.json

# set entry file
sed -i '' "s/index.js/index.$1.js/" package.json

# set output folder
sed -i '' "s/TARGET/$1/" package.json

# package app
npm run build

# get rid of electron config package.json
rm package.json

# "reset" old package.json
mv _package.json package.json
```

and my package.json scripts looks like

```
{
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
  "reinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=development electron src/index.development.js",
  "build": "build -mw",
  "build:development": "sh scripts/build.sh development",
  "build:pilot": "sh scripts/build.sh pilot",
  "build:pilot2": "sh scripts/build.sh pilot2",
  "build:production": "sh scripts/build.sh production",
  "build:all":
    "npm run build:development && npm run build:pilot && npm run build:pilot2 && npm run build:production",
  "test": "npm run postinstall && jest"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this with [electron-build config](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) `extraMetadata`, you can override package.json properties during build with it.

```
const builder = require('electron-builder');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const entry = `index.${env}.js`;

builder.build({
  config: {
    extraMetadata: {
      main: entry
    },
    appId: 'com.electron.foo',
    productName: 'foo',
    mac: {
      target: 'zip'
    },
    win: {
      target: 'portable'
    },
    portable: {
      artifactName: 'foo.exe'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you implement this ? in package.json all we add is build .how do you overwrite package.json configuration .